# What is the cause of the following error?

Tags: paddle-paddle

NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'IVector_create'.

Possible C/C++ prototypes are:

```
IVector::create(std::vector< int,std::allocator< int > > const &,bool)
IVector::create(std::vector< int,std::allocator< int > > const &)
```

Comment: if you add minimal code which results in the same error, you're more likely to get help

Answer (score 0):

This is because the data type of the parameter is incorrectly written in the code, or the function name is written incorrectly.